# median and standard deviation chart using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to draw a chart as seen in attached image using highcharts or any js library but i am not getting any lead. Anyone any thoughts?[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the purpose/layout of the chart - it seems more suited to a simple table...  However, I would say you can achieve such a display using highcharts. Some of the part of these bullet chart examples could be used for it:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/QM6kF/ | http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/UGs2E/

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question but I just ran across it while looking for how to display a similar chart: one that shows median and standard deviation around the median, but also can show the outlier low and high values. Highcharts actually has a very good solution for this called a boxplot that I eventually stumbled across. I mention it here in case it can help someone else. Worked well for me and I think would have worked well for the OP (with some modification).

Here is the highcharts demo page:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot